# GitHub Actions : How to test the ouput of shell command

Tags: java, shell, github, github-actions, javadoc

### Introduction

I'm currently writing a GitHub workflow inside a GitHub Action that tests the creation of JavaDoc files.
The project of the GitHub Action when I want to add this GitHub Worklow: https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Javadoc-publisher.yml

### Problem

Problem, my GitHub workflow doesn't fail when the folder doesn't contain the expected files.

```yaml
      # Test that the javadoc folder is created
      - name: Check that the javadoc folder is created
        run: |
          git fetch
          git checkout javadoc-test
          ls javadoc
        bash: shell
```

### Question

Does someone know how to use the [GitHub Workflow expression](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) with the output of the shell command?

Or how to exit the workflow with an error when the Javadoc folder is not on the project?

Comment: Workflow Expressions are meant to set environment variables, access contexts of the workflow, or programmatically decided if a step needs to run or not. Nothing in your example above actually checks to see if the files you are expected are there or not. You will need to write a script or custom action to check if the files exists.

Comment: @tj-cappelletti Thank you for your comment, I updated my Question. Do you have a suggestion for a script or custom action to check if the files exist?

Comment: Could [this action](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/assert-command-line-output) helps you achieve what you want?